# Can I read flash from an MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, stm8

I have two ICs with STM8S005C6 MCUs.

Is it possible to read flash from MCU of the first IC and write it to the other one?

I checked the STMZ website for tools to read/write to MCU but they seem to use JTAG and my IC doesn't have JTAG.

- What should I look for?
- What pins of the MCU are used for reading/writing operations? So I can follow those pins and maybe find myself a tag to read from it on the IC.

Comment: You can implement a software JTAG protocol by bit banging the i/o pins and read the flash of the other MCU. Or you can use a JTAG to read the flash and transfer the read data to your second MCU.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack what programmer should i get for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the protection bits are not set, You will need the ST-Link programmer. It supports the SWIM protocol, used by the ST8 MCUs. Alternately, you can, with a debugger, write a RAM resident program that dumps the flash memory to a UART.

Comment: st-link is not required, the swim interface is documented.  can access one mcu from the other

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [ST Visual Programmer STM8](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stvp-stm8.html). You will need to have a [STLINK/V2](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html) programmer. These connect to the SWIM/SWD pins. [Cheaper options are also available.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1PCS-ST-LINK-Stlink-ST-Link-V2-Mini-STM8-STM32-Simulator-Download-Programmer-Programming-With-Cover/32792513237.html)